# image in html left turn 90 degree automatically issue

Tags: html

I got a problem of displaying image and I know this sound silly perhaps but I really facing this kind of problem the first time.

image URL : https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/KvxFiFSYQj1hGip67E0C?cache=true&w=320

if I open in browser directly then no problem.

if I open thru html like below:

```
<img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/KvxFiFSYQj1hGip67E0C?cache=true&w=320">
```

then the image left turn 90 degree automatically. you can do this in http://jsfiddle.net/ and will see the result.

Appreciate some help please. thanks !

regards,
Mark

Comment: You should of just made a fiddle instead of linking fiddle site and tell other people to try it  http://jsfiddle.net/BCFkN/ Looks like it's the site must be doing it since they want you to pay to upload images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is rotated by using its EXIF metadata. The browser `<img>` tag doesn't respect this for some reason

[image: exif rotate]

You can use a tool like [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to rotate the image correctly. With it installed, run:

```
convert source.jpg -auto-orient dest.jpg
```

After some research into this, apparently there's a new CSS property, `image-orientation` that can fix this without changing the image. Unfortunately, [only firefox supports this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-orientation) (as of July 2014).

```
img {
    image-orientation: from-image;
}
```

Since you use filepicker.io, you can use their image conversion tools to do the job. By adding `/convert?rotate=exif` after the file handle, the image is automatically rotated by its exif data.

```
<img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/KvxFiFSYQj1hGip67E0C/convert?w=320&rotate=exif">
```

[Result fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCFkN/1/)

Comment: hi parchment. the problem here is that i got a lot of user upload photo themself thru my website and I do not know which one is rotated and which one is not. I am using filepicker.io to upload photo.

Comment: @MarkThien Browsing through the filepicker docs, I believe I found something that should help. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: hi parchment, the "from-image" is the image url ?

Comment: @MarkThien the `from-image` is the css keyword that means the image will be automatically rotated by its exif data. Keep in mind that that css currently only works in firefox. I've edited the post

Comment: yeah I got it and I tried it in jsfiddle and it works only in firefox. but this solution doesn't completely work for me as a few photos will be displayed on a page and I will not know which one need to be rotated as your solution is to rotate every image. Even image that correctly display also got rotated.

Comment: @MarkThien filepicker.io will automatically rotate images that need to be rotated if you add `/convert?rotate=exif`. The only thing that would be an issue is that the image conversions are not free in filepicker.io right?

Comment: hi Parchment, ok I got it. I overlooked your solution. just append "&rotate=exif" to every filepicker image url will do. Really thanks a lot man. I love you. Cheerio :)

Comment: How can this be done when the image source is a file on the computer and not from the internet?