# Ipad uploaded image shows 90 degree rotated in desktop all browsers in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have uploaded image from Ipad/Iphone (Captured in Iphone/Ipad). It's showing perfect in Ipad/Iphone browsers, but in desktop all browsers', it's showing 90 degree rotated.

`<img>` tag is as below,

```
<img id="Main_SettingMain_imgPhoto" style="height:100px;width:100px;" src="/Images/UserProfile/test.jpg">
```

This image is in portrait mode but it displaying in landscape mode in all desktop browsers.

```
According to this link,
```

[image in html left turn 90 degree automatically issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784117/image-in-html-left-turn-90-degree-automatically-issue), i put css but it only allow in mozilla browser. I have to make this `<img>` tag compatible in all Desktop browsers'.

Any suggestion acceptable.

Comment: I referred this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565507/camera-image-changes-orientation and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this issue while working for one website, The Issue is not with your code its with Image . Because it is captured with Iphone/Ipad.

Use Photoshop to edit Image, and save it in Jpg format or accordingly. 
It wont Flip on any browser.

It worked for me. Give it a try!

Comment: Don't Just use the Images captured with Iphone or Ipad as it is, Edit a bit in photoshop or anyother tool and save it again newly in required format. 

This will work For sure.

Comment: yes but the image uploaded by user and it directly shows in image tag. so i have no choice to alter it with Photoshop

Comment: Oh I thought It is static. You can detect the browser with Js and apply -webkit- accordingly

Comment: I already applied -webkit and image-orientation in css but nothing worked